# What is the name of this Ravenloft adventure featuring a vampire innkeeper and a werewolf that kills villagers?

Tags: published-adventures, adnd-2e, product-identification, ravenloft

When I started playing *Dungeons & Dragons*, it was in second edition, Ravenloft Campaign.

I remember playing an adventure where it was a small village in the snow, where a werewolf was killing villagers, and the innkeeper was a vampire. I really can't remember the name of the adventure or the module, but it was an official Ravenloft module, can someone help me? I wanted to try to buy that module in second hand, I remember it has several adventures.

What is the name of this Ravenloft adventure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh, finally I discovered which one it is. I found the answer by checking some forums talking about Ravenloft and the published modules.

It is in the *Book of Crypts* anthology, in the module *Blood in Moondale*. The vampire is [Dante Lysin](https://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Dante_Lysin):

> Dante Lysin (real name: Dante Curare) is a Nosferatu Vampire and the proprietor of the Moondale Inn. A former gladiator and slave who killed his master, Dante eventually made his way to Moondale and purchased an inn. Over the next several years, nosferatu vampires menaced Moondale. Dante Lysin was one of their victims, drained of his blood and transformed into one of their number. However, when his vampire master was slain, Dante was given free will and concealed his true nature.
>
> Dante hates his condition, but has yet to search for a cure. As a nosferatu vampire, he can live off of animal blood and survive, albeit in a slightly weakened state. However, his undeath is slowly.
>
> Dante Lysin is featured in the Book of Crypts module Blood in Moondale. Over the course of the events in that module, Dante may become implicated as the cause of the murders, though he is innocent.

Thanks all, now it's time to buy it secondhand =)

Comment: You can get the PDF of *Book of Crypts* from DMsGuild for $5 here: https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17489/RR2-Book-of-Crypts-2e

Answer (score 5):

## I suspect...

[Dark of the Moon](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17504/Dark-of-the-Moon-2e?filters=45471_0_0_0_0_0_0_0) (D&D Classics link), "set in the frozen, snowy wood of Vorostokov," featuring a lycanthropic lord trying to gain control. Reading through the preview-available pages I don't see a vampire-innkeep mentioned, but it *is* Ravenloft....

I've just read through the [mistpedia](https://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Dark_of_the_Moon) summaries (where available) or the D&D Classics summaries and previews of [2e Ravenloft modules](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=45471_0_45393_0_45359_45347_0_0) of the adventures in this [(self-proclaimed) complete list of 2e products at dragonsfeet](https://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11454), and this really looks like the only one in the neighborhood.

(And it was kinda fun reading back through some of those old plotlines--it's probably been 25 years since I read a Ravenloft novel, so thanks for the trip down memory lane!)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i think its not that one =( it was a module with several adventures, maybe i´m mistaken, not sure.

Comment: Sorry, then--but hopefully some of the links help you on your quest. Happy trails!

Answer (score 4):

I agree that *Dark of the Moon* sounds like your werewolf story... but if you're looking for a module that contains multiple adventures and a vampire innkeeper, the closest I could find was *Chilling Tales.* It features seven adventures and a vampire who runs a hospice, which was the closest I could find to a vampiric innkeeper. It also has a werewolf-based adventure, though it doesn't explicitly take place in the snow like *Dark of the Moon* does.